# Is there anywhere simple parachain runtime example with XCM reserved transfer functionality from relay chain to parachain and back?

Tags: parachain, runtime, xcm, relay-chain, xcmp

I wonder if there is some example of (parachain)runtime with xcm-pallet and orml-xtokens configuration for education purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to confirm that the parachain supports the assets of the relay chain. (Check their assets pallet or other assets releated pallet)

Then follow the example to transfer between kusama(1000) and karura(2000):

1. Kusama transfer KSM to parachain(2000) use `xcm-pallet`
   [image]
2. parachain(2000) transfer KSM to Kusama use `xtokens`
   [image]