# WeightLimitReached Error occured when executing ReserveTransferAssets with XCM

Tags: parachain, xcm

I'm testing the ReserveTransferAssets, but it didn't work well.

When Trappist chain send XCM from statemine to base Parachain, `WeightLimitReached` and `xcmpQueue.OverweightEnqueued` error occurred. But I don't know the exact reason.(Already tried to change buying weight fee)

I used this encoded data:
`0x1f030208000400010300a10f04320504000b005039278c04100100010100a10f08130000020432050400070010a5d4e8000e010004010100e12e040d010004000101008eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a4800e40b5402000000`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Hi Hugo, please write your question here instead of linking to it. Try to boil down your problem to the smallest possible unit and phrase it as a question.

Comment: usually we do not introduce ourselfs in the question

Comment: Thanks, updated it!

Comment: Are you running a local network with zombienet o maybe running local nodes?.
I tried to do the same following [this example](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/blob/master/xcm-simulator/src/tests/xcm_use_cases.rs#L224-L358), the weight from there are different, for example the amount in ByExecution is 65000000000 and not 1000000000000, but I get the same errors using those amounts.

Comment: yes, exactly, I run the local testnet using zombienet. Could you tell me the exact function name and error code? I solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reserveTransfer tokens from one chain to another chain, please use `polkadotXcm.reserveTransferAssets` or `polkadotXcm.limitedreserveTransferAssets` instead of `polkadot.execute`.

BTW, not relevant to this question, you seems want to send XCM to para(3000), but there's no parachain which paraId is 3000 under Kusama. Maybe you need learn more about HRMP and XCM, you can check [this doc](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-xcm) or others.

---

ReserveTransfer example:

relay chain <> parachain: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4886/1959

Comment: I left out the details. I worked on the local testnet and used the reserveTransferAsset to transfer the asset from statemine to trappist para. After that, this question is about transfering the asset which reserved at stamine, from the trappist to another parachain. 

And It was a weight setting problem in statemine and I solved it. Thank you for your help!