# WeightLimitReached Error

Tags: xcm

I'm running a local network using zombienet, I want to transfer assets between parachains, I'm trying to do [this example](https://youtu.be/UfxU3hUprKo?t=1760). The thing is when I send the extrinsic on Trappist, and the extrinsic is processed in statemine I get this error:

[image]

The extrinsic in trappist:

[image]

I also followed [this instructions](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist/blob/master/xcm-simulator/src/tests/xcm_use_cases.rs#L224-L358) to make the extrinsic.

I already set asset in statemine as sufficient, and the asset in trappist as multilocation. Did I miss something?

Comment: Duplicate with https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7146/weightlimitreached-error-occured-when-executing-reservetransferassets-with-xcm

Comment: I saw it, I think he's running a local network too. We're not using any parachain on kusama, so the parachain with id 3000 exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. This error occurs because Xcm fee (weight 52,840,547,000) excuted on the statemine is higher than weight limit(weight_limit: 41,666,666,666).

To resolve this issue, clone the statemine repository from cumulus and change almost weights to 1_u64 as below image. After newly building polkadot-parachain, put this realesed polkadot-parachain to the path where you set zombienet config for statmine.

[image]

Although error disappear, it is not a realistic solution. So I'm checking why the weight is calculated so high in the statemine. If you have any question, feel free to ask me.

Comment: What exactly are the ones I need to change and what version of cumulus are you using?

Comment: In the image attached above, all the weights in all the file names in yellow were changed to 1. All versions I use are v0.9.36.

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7197/1959

You should use `polkadotXcm.reserveTransferAssets` or `polkadotXcm.limitedreserveTransferAssets` rather than `polkadot.execute`.